# connecting to a remote MS ACCESS database in java

Tags: java, ms-access

I am developing application in java which is having back end in MS Access.
 it works fine on a local MS Access database using the following connection string:

```
 DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver  (*.mdb)};Dbq=d:\test.mdb");
```

What will be the connection string to connect to a Remote MS ACCESS database on another
 machine.
 please reply......

Comment: Have you tried googling? http://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on JET, but I thought you had to have access to the .mdb file directly. Have you tried the samba url instead of the file name?

Comment: why not make it an answer? @Hans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how you are able to connect to the other machine.  You can connect if the remote copy of `test.mdb` is available from a file share on the other machine on the same LAN.

For a share mapped to drive letter X:

```
Dbq=X:\test.mdb
```

Or use the UNC path:

```
Dbq=\\machine_name\share_name\test.mdb
```

If you can't use either of those, Access is not suitable and you should choose a different database for your data storage.

Note, I'm assuming both the local and remote machine are running MS Windows.  If either or both are running a different operating system, you should tell us which OS is used.